# How to add a login to a tab

Tags: users

I have a website, but I want to figure out how to create a tab or link within the website that users would have to log in to view. There would most likely be one set of log in information that everyone in my organization would use. For example, maybe the username is org27 and password is 222orgs and everyone would use that to access the tab or link. How would I do that or is that even possible? Thank you.

Comment: What content are you wanting to keep hidden? Are you wanting to control a particular content type or an individual page?

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at the module, Protected Pages.  https://www.drupal.org/project/protected_pages
It seems your tab would direct users to a particular page with sensitive or unique information pertaining to only those users.  In that case a simple module protecting those pages might do the trick.